# Add-PnPNavigationNode - How to set node order?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, navigation, pnp-powershell

Quick question: Does anyone know of a way to change the order of the nodes in let's say the QuickLaunch nav when adding them via Add-PnPNavigationNode? I only know of the `-first` parameter.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/2759 I have the same problem, I hope it is possible to adjust the order @Declan Turner I don't know how to use C# code in powershell If NavigationNodeCreationInformation Class is useful, can you give me the code that can run in powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate this is a few months old but I had a similar problem today. When adding a new node with CSOM, using the NavigationNodeCreationInformation class, you can specify the previous node. If you need to reorder existing nodes programmatically, I think you would have to delete and recreate them (haven't found a way to reorder existing nodes).

[NavigationNodeCreationInformation Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.navigationnodecreationinformation)

Answer (score 2):

To set the order of node in Quick launch, we can only use CSOM to update the relevant node via AsLastNode property.

Reference: [NavigationNode class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee541448(v=office.15))

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I've interpreted correctly but let's assume we have three nodes: node 1-3. Now I want node 1 to become node 2. How would I do that if I can only specify a node to become the last one?